# Close Tab after file download using Javascript/React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

New tab gets opened if i want to download a file.
In the below code i have closed the new tab after 10 sec. but the time should not be hardcoded.
it should be the time taken for file download.
Any suggestion how to calculate time taken for file download?

```js
<a  href='' onClick={(e)=>activeTab(e,link) }>{filename} </a>

  const activeTab=(e,url)=> {
   const newWindow = window.open(url, '_blank');
   var startTime = (new Date().getTime());
   var endTime;
    if (newWindow) {
      //newWindow.opener =null
      if(newWindow.opener){
        setTimeout ( function () {
            newWindow.close ();
       }, 10000
      )
    }
    endTime = new Date().getTime()
  }
    e.preventDefault ();
    e.stopPropagation ();
  }
```

Please suggest me for any solutions.

Comment: I'd recommend to use a different approach. What if a user has a slow PC or slow internet? Download won't be finished and cancelled?
Maybe you can try to download the file in the current tab, save it to memory and provide it as download "inline".

Comment: Is there any way we can know if file download is completed?

Comment: It depends on what technology you use and how your download actually works in the frontend. For example if you use axios (or a different Promise-based http client) you can use basic `Promise` to handle download completion.